# Perl variables defined with * vs $

Tags: perl, variables

What's the difference between defining a variable with a * vs a $?  For example:

```
local $var;
local *var;
```

Comment: Also, you almost certainly mean to be using `my` instead of `local`.

Comment: It's important to note that typeglobs are specific to package-scoped variables, and variables declared with `my` will not have an associated typeglob or symbol table entry. The documentation pertaining to this is very dense and is far more useful as referential material than introductory material. I recommend Bruce Gray's [Why `my`?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ton-5tvDQiE) talk, as it helped me understand package variables as both a historical artifact of Perl and the specific situations in which they continue to be useful (such as for imports).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The initial character is known as a [*sigil*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_%28magic%29#Alternative_Usage), and says what sort of value the identifier represents. You will know most of them. Here's a list

- Dollar `$` is a *scalar* value
- At sign `@` is an *array* value
- Percent `%` is a *hash* value
- Ampersand `&` is a *code* value
- Asterisk `*` is a *typeglob*

You are less likely to have come across the last two recently, because `&` hasn't been necessary when calling subroutines since Perl 5.0 was released. And typeglobs are a special type that contains all of the other types, and are much more rarely used.

I'm considering how much deeper to go into all of this, but will leave my answer as it is for now. I may write more depending on the comments that arise.

Answer (score 7):

`$var` is a scalar. `*var` is a typeglob. http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Typeglobs-and-Filehandles

It's not a variable in the strictest sense. You shouldn't generally be using it.

Comment: Hey, thanks!  I had never seen a typeglob before, so I was having a hard time trying to find the answer on my own...